# Function to generate a UUID

Tags: php, security, random

I am trying to prevent CSRF for my login page (linked from [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115990/creating-a-login-page)), and for this I am going to use a random token generator to create a UUID for the session.

The function that I have so far is as such:

```
function UUID()
{
    mt_srand((double)microtime()*10000);
    $charid = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)));
    $hyphen = chr(45);
    $uuid =  substr($charid, 0, 8).$hyphen
            .substr($charid, 8, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,12, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,16, 4).$hyphen
            .substr($charid,20,12);
    return $uuid;
}
```

This function is working perfect and on a loop of 30 runs it gives me this result:

> E1BDBF20-A481-AD53-648F-C89E5242B934
>   E2329CE9-B79D-999A-C61F-65C3C3976EBE
>   B2FE5771-60DE-9E9B-ADF2-1A78B6BD8BC4
>   77384406-B472-8192-E301-50CCA1E0CC10
>   7854EF9F-991F-90D9-ACA5-07C01C25F355
>   EB4D6BC0-6AB1-9020-0C94-BCB81C540EA9
>   0AAABBCC-B53F-AF23-2D18-92B971AFD76C
>   298FAE1A-F25A-7BF9-ECA9-3C5E80CCBC82
>   0533A8D8-AC1F-3A94-FD51-8A95B69DB9C7
>   CC650B31-14B6-8709-9E6C-84AA307E77DA
>   52AEE9D4-FAC4-7AEC-DB31-882CA61A6AE6
>   EED5154B-7425-ED7C-95A1-2239A79F0FAC
>   42094233-09D7-BB08-8404-908889B5AB6C
>   1A3C9D28-4FF3-5A4B-1994-AFE189D02C01
>   4F5D3BC5-C94A-CFD5-87C1-4E2903811DF0
>   6BC0612C-93EE-DE33-299B-44888BCCC670
>   D7029641-ED26-C136-C5BB-6A6C932A1354
>   AB3CF87D-8FA1-C38F-13AA-BFEEA016122C
>   687DC395-CF5C-2797-F825-9122D179D6B4
>   7970708B-F266-B308-6DA5-49DB190C9326
>   ABF5494D-C8B3-976D-42D6-FE108BFF593E
>   F0A3A1C0-3A57-EED3-54FB-60C644C8F329
>   7A687548-B0B3-E266-E473-74E9BE6D45BE
>   A445E134-A9FD-E554-D6E7-E6D1DE9D1046
>   F8FCE8F8-7B2C-92E4-00B3-9F834BCE1E9A
>   982E093A-0D93-AEAC-DEC3-EFEFA9401EEE
>   353E75FC-80B5-6177-F987-4EAF77BC4F97
>   8262F39E-F4C0-B60B-9007-A533BC043600
>   3810166A-38AC-1275-2593-922CD25E42C6
>   59E6A361-8FEA-FE81-B75E-927FC439159E

But it seems like there is a better way of creating this, although I have tried to use `com_create_guid`, this did not give quite the result I wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `mt_srand` seeds the rng for `mt_rand`, not for `rand`. What you probably want is `srand`. Although seeding it with the time is not that good of an idea, as time is a value an attacker might guess.

But really, there is no reason to use `rand` in the first place (the documentation also warns against using it when secure values are needed). Just use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`:

```
base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));
```

I don't really see a reason to place hyphens in-between the characters. It doesn't really add anything. It just makes the token longer, without adding randomness. I also don't see a reason for `strtoupper`, it even reduces randomness.

Also note that `uniqid` is not supposed to be used for any security purposes. If we assume that it is completely broken (which it is probably not, but I haven't looked at the code, and it does have a big warning in the documentation), that would only leave you with 10 random numerical characters (from a not-so-great rng), which doesn't seem that great.

I don't think that there is really a security issue with what you have, but it is definitely not the correct approach. Just use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` instead. It's definitely more secure, and the code is considerably shorter, and can easily be adapted (just change `32` to `64` if you want more security; with your code, you would have to change a lot more).

Comment: At least I am mostly used to seeing UUID's with hyphens.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely good point. UUID is probably the wrong name for a CSRF token anyways (which doesn't need to be universally unique, and doesn't really identify anything). The hyphens are there so it's human readable, but that's really not needed for a CSRF token.